# After downloading .ipa file I'm getting message "Unable to Download App" but only for newest versions of Ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

After downloading .ipa file which I got from Xcode I'm getting message

> Unable to Download App

but only for newest versions of iPad.

On the iPad air and so one it's working fine. I adjusted build settings option in xcode to the last versions of iOS and Arm64 sdk but still it's not working... Any solutions?

Comment: You use diawi ?? check whether that device added to the provision profile of the app

Comment: How are you downloading it?

Comment: I'm uploading to hockeyapp and from there I'm downloading to my device. It's working good on all older devices...

Comment: check that device uuid is listed in provision profile or not

Comment: Have you registered the new devices on hockeyapp?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with generating new key, certificate profile and provision profile.